# Form does not submits automatically on time over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a quiz module where the quiz has to be submitted automatically if it crosses the time limit i.e. 30 mins. I have used jquery for this but somehow the quiz doesn't submits automatically when time limit reaches. may I know where am I going wrong. Any insight to this will be very helpful. Following is my code snippet,

```
function get15dayFromNow() {   

   return new Date(new Date().valueOf() + <?php echo $duration ; ?> * 60 * 1000);

       }

   var $time_spend = $('#time_spend');
  $time_spend.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
    $(this).val(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
  });

  var $clock = $('#clock');
  $clock.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
    $(this).html('Time Left :   '+'00:'+event.strftime('%M:%S'));

    var counterVal  =   $("#clock").text();
    if((counterVal   == '00:00') || (counterVal   == '00:00:00'))
    { 
        submitForm(); 
    }

 });

function submitForm()
{
    document.getElementById("target").submit();

}

 <div class="lead" style="width:30%; text-align:right; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" id="clock"><?php echo $duration ; ?>:00</div>
<form id="target" method="post" action="processQuiz_chapter.php">

//Question and options listings here.

 <button type="submit" style="display:none;"  name="submitQuiz" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Submit</button>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit_togle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try to replace submitForm() with alert(). see if it actually runs.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have tried it, but no it does not shows alert(); too.

Comment: which means, the problem is the checking might not be correct.

Comment: Can I know if this can be rectified? Or some other way to do the same.

Comment: Could you provide `$time_spend.countdown()` and `$clock.countdown()` to us?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Thanks for your reply. `echo '<input type="hidden" name="time_spend" value="$duration" id="time_spend">';` and `<div class="lead" style="width:30%; text-align:right; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" id="clock"><?php echo '30' ; ?>:00</div>`

Comment: I meant the `countdown()` function itself, where does it come from? Do you use a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using a file `jquery.countdown.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to keep you js code in document ready function,

There is an event which will execute on completion of your time, you can use that 
event to submit the form. Look at the line having text as **finish.countdown**

Try following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function get15dayFromNow() {   

       return new Date(new Date().valueOf() + <?php echo $duration ; ?> * 60 * 1000);

           }

       var $time_spend = $('#time_spend');
          $time_spend.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
            $(this).val(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
          });

       var $clock = $('#clock');
        $clock.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
            $(this).html('Time Left :   '+'00:'+event.strftime('%M:%S'));
        })
        .on('finish.countdown', function() {
            submitForm();
        });

    function submitForm()
    {
        document.getElementById("target").submit();

    }
});
```

Read more on [Document](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#controls)

Comment: Thank you Alpesh for the time. But as you can see I have posted my answer as it resolves the things for me.

Comment: @Ansh, That is true, but I would suggest if you are using API then you should use available events and resource from API instead of adding hacks, As I see you are comparing string to achieve you goal,  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for being informative. I will definitely give this a try and will let you know about this . Still thanks for being supportive and rectifying. Keep up the good work Alpesh :)

Comment: Hi again. I had sorted this issue long back. Now I want to show an alert box just one minute before the form submitting time. How can this be implemented in the above mentioned function. Please shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Finally its sorted now. The lines

```
if((counterVal   == '00:00') || (counterVal   == '00:00:00'))
    { 
        submitForm(); 
    }
```

had to be replaced by ,

```
if((counterVal   == 'Time Left :   00:00:00') || (counterVal   == 'Time Left :   00:00'))
    { 
        submitForm(); 
    }
```