# Javascript start countdown and at the end call ajax

Tags: javascript

I am trying to start the Javascript countdown using following Javascript code. Here it's counting from **5 - 0**.

Now I want when It's **0** then I will call an Ajax request (I know how to do it). But for now, I set it alert message that your session ends.

It continuously showing me the alert message But it's should be **once!**

**Here is the JS code:**

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;


        if(timer !== 0 ) {
            --timer;
        } else if( timer == 0 ) {
            alert('Your time has been completed.');
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var seconds = 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(seconds, display);
};
```

Comment: you might got answer , you should try rxjs that might be helpful

Comment: You can try http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ this JS plugin, which has lot many methods and events like **finish.countdown**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423210/form-does-not-submits-automatically-on-time-over/49428522#49428522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the interval to a variable, so that you can then clear the interval after the final `alert` so that it doesn't run anymore:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  let timer = duration;
  const interval = setInterval(function() {
    let minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    let seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (timer !== 0) {
      --timer;
    } else if (timer == 0) {
      alert('Your time has been completed.');
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var seconds = 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(seconds, display);
};
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks my lack of js knowledge :(

Comment: One more question if you can. In that time period If I load the page then it's should show me an alert() message. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just put `alert('message here')` right after the `window.onload` line

Comment: Thanks a lot Man.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make use of `clearInterval()` method as below

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
myTimer() {
  if(conditionMet)
   clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

or just for info you can make use of [interval of react js](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html)

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = interval(1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => {
 if(conditionmet)
   source.unsubscribe(); 
 console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**ES5**

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {

var timer = duration;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
if (timer !== 0) {
  --timer;
} else if (timer == 0) {
  alert('Your time has been completed.');
  clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);

}

  window.onload = function() {
  var seconds = 5,
  display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(seconds, display);
};
```